# Asterisk character in CSS class name

Tags: css, class, character

What do these CSS class names exactly do?

```
visible-xs-*
```

I want to know the role of trailing * character. these class name are marked invalid in my editor as shown in attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *looks* like a poor coding version of Bootstraps show/hide classes which hasn't been completed properly.

[image]